# How to create a temporary table with hibernate

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate

I have a oracle database, I need to use a temporary table, I know that I must use `CREATE GLOBAL TEMPORARY TABLE` to create my table, but I would like to know how do it with hibernate, can someone help me please?

Comment: Nothing for now :P , I don't know how to do it, but I knew that there are some settings on hibernate mapping files to delete tables, but I don't remember very well.

Comment: Basically google before you stack.

Comment: Why does hibernate need to create the table? Just create it once and then let hibernate use it.

Comment: Firtsly, I'm using hibernate for my process, second my process is automatic, then the table must be created at that moment and the table must be temporary, because it's only support for processing data which will be stored in another tables.